# How to put a box in aligned equations?

Tags: align, box

Can someone help me with the following question?

I'm writing an equation like this:

```
\begin{align*}
   a =& b - c \\
     -& d - e
\end{align*}
```

How can I put a box around the part

```
b - c \\
d - e
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{array}{r@{}|l|}
\cline{2-2}
a =& b - c \\
     -& d - e\\
\cline{2-2}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much!